# Image or Css for mobile web-site

Tags: css, image, mobile

Considering how many screen sizes for Android, I am thinking should I put an image for toolbar  and splash image or responsive background css image.

I am developing a mobile web-site.

**CSS:**

1. Good for multiple screens, so it can be responsive
2. Hard to develop especially if a Photoshop guy can do that within 10-15 mins :)

**IMAGE**

1. Hard to create a responsive image? Correct me if I'm wrong
2. Fast development.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want a responsive image, you could simply give the element a `width` of `100%`. You *might* also need to add `height:auto` in order to preserve the aspect ratio of the image.

[**EXAMPLE HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/5QyrB/)

```
img {
    height:auto;
    width:100%;
}
```

Comment: Holy, moly, that was easy :)